# Parsing xml file using beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the stuff tag from profile name="4" only. I have written a code below that extracts everything under profile name = "4" but is there a way from there to collect all the stuff tags or would I have to use split to get the text inside the stuff tag. The xml file that I have is much longer so using split is doable but it would take much longer to parse the data.

This is the python code

```
import bs4 as bs

# opens xml file and allows bs4 to parse xml file
xml_file = open('file.xml')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(xml_file, 'html.parser')

#extracts and prints all tags under profile name = "4"
stuff = soup.find_all('profile', {'name':"4"})
print stuff
```

This is the xml file and its called file.xml. I want to extract the stuff tags from profile name = "4"

```
<profiles>
    <profile name="1">
        <content>apple</content>
    </profile>
    <profile name="2">
        <content>peas</content>
    </profile>
    <profile name="3">
        <stuff>bear</stuff>
    </profile>
    <profile name="4">
        <content>cat</content>
        <data>
            <stuff>fish</stuff>
        </data>
        <stuff>hat</stuff>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the the same for inner tags

```
print([i.find_all('stuff') for i in stuff])
```

If you just need data inside the tags

```
for i in stuff:
    for x in i.find_all('stuff'):
        print(x.next)
```

Output:

```
fish
hat
```